# Cannot update listview through activity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-activity

I have created an `listview` based app in which when I add data through another activity the data doesn't get updated in the `listview` where as it should get updated in the listview !!

when I have created an `onSave` method on the save button in the activity but it doesnt seem to get updated in the list view.

**mainactivity.java**

```
package com.example.listviewdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TimeTrackerAdapter timeTrackerAdapter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView listView = (ListView)
                findViewById(R.id.times_list);
                timeTrackerAdapter = new TimeTrackerAdapter();
                listView.setAdapter(timeTrackerAdapter);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu m) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(m);
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.time_list_menu, m );
        return true;
    }

    public static final int TIME_ENTRY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.add_time_menu_item) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddTimeActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, TIME_ENTRY_REQUEST_CODE);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == TIME_ENTRY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String notes = data.getStringExtra("notes");
                String time = data.getStringExtra("time");

                timeTrackerAdapter.addTimeRecord( new TimeRecord(time, notes));
                timeTrackerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            }
    }



}
```

**addtimeactivity.java**

```
package com.example.listviewdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AddTimeActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_time);
        }
    public void onCancel(View view) {
        finish();
    }
    public void onSave(View view) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        EditText timeView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.time_view);
        intent.putExtra("time", timeView.getText().toString());

        EditText notesView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.notes_view);
        intent.putExtra("notes", notesView.getText().toString());

        this.setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

**timetrackeradapter.java**

```
    package com.example.listviewdemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TimeTrackerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<TimeRecord> times = new ArrayList<TimeRecord>();
    public TimeTrackerAdapter() {
        times.add(new TimeRecord(
                "38:23", "Feeling good!"));
                times.add(new TimeRecord(
                "49:01", "Tired. Needed more caffeine"));
                times.add(new TimeRecord(
                "26:21", "I’m rocking it!"));
                times.add(new TimeRecord(
                "29:42", "Lost some time on the hills, but pretty good."));     
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return times.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int index) {
        return getItem(index);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int index) {
        return index;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int index, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater =
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            view = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.time_list_item, parent, false);
        }
        TimeRecord time = times.get(index);
        TextView timeTextView = (TextView)
                view.findViewById(R.id.time_view);
        timeTextView.setText(time.getTime());
        TextView notesTextView = (TextView)
                view.findViewById(R.id.notes_view);
        notesTextView.setText(time.getNotes());
        return view;

    }

    public void addTimeRecord(TimeRecord timeRecord) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }





}
```

Comment: Start working it backwards. Did the onResults get called? Did you make it inside your if statements? Keep going that way until you find the issue.

Comment: i aint getting the issue , i even tried to debug with the help of the breakpoints, but not of any use @PearsonArtPhoto

Comment: Through what point have you confirmed that things seem to be working?

Comment: things have been working except the data aint getting added in the listview as it is supposed to

Comment: You really need to include the code for `TimeTrackerAdapter`, as everything seems to be working that you have as it should, but I'm not sure what `TimeTrackerAdapter` even is, let alone if it's doing the right thing.

Comment: it doesnt shows any errors but neither it shows improvements !! i have included the code for time tracker adapter (in two mins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
public void addTimeRecord(TimeRecord timeRecord) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

You haven't actually implemented this function, and so it won't do anything! My guess is you want to do this:

```
public void addTimeRecord(TimeRecord timeRecord) {
    times.add(timeRecord);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Note that with this, you don't need the redundant `notifyDataSetChanged()` in your first activity.

Comment: err, that worked out, while creating the onActivityResult addTimeRecored was generating errors, for which i resulted in generating the auto generated method to suppress the error. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why is your `addTimeRecord` is empty?

Try this,

```
public void addTimeRecord(TimeRecord timeRecord) {
    times.add(timeRecord);
}
```

Comment: yes as i said it became to be an auto generated method so i did not payed much attention to it, much of my ignorance. it works with times.add(timeRecord); thank you !!